# How to overwrite a jar file in a maven generated war?

Tags: java, maven

I has been copying some patched jars inside war files in order to test remediated jars without uploading them to the maven repo, and everything goes well when applying the maven-war-plugin as long as the jar does no exists they are placed inside the war, so no overwrite is happening, but the copy does happen.

Those jar files belong to several dependencies which I have no control whatsoever and could be any number of files, also I can't replace them in the nexus before testing nor place them in my local repo, since the idea is to generate the war file in other machines using jenkins to test the jars.

So, how can I overwrite the jar files that are packaged into the war file?

This is my previous configuration that allows me to copy any number of jars from a libs folder to the WEB-INF/lib inside the war file.

```
<!-- OVERWRITE JAR files with remediated versions -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>default-war</id>
              <phase>none</phase>
            </execution>
            <execution>
              <id>war-replace</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <webResources>
                  <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/libs</directory>
                    <includes>
                      <include>**/*.jar</include>
                      <include>**/*.war</include>
                    </includes>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib/</targetPath>
                  </resource>
                </webResources>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that you solve with these changed jars?  There might be a better way.

Comment: To verify changes in said jars as requested by fortify.

Comment: You know of SNAPSHOT versions also don't configure maven-war-plugin and violate the conventions...Apart from that your process sounds wrong..what do you need to test war's ? Do you use CI tools like Jenkins?

Comment: As I said before, I do not control the dependencies, thats why I need this unconventional approach. I need to inject those jar so they can be verified by other team, they use jenkins to create the war and upload it to the server.